# Convert Array into dataframe with columns and index in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Initially I have a matrix

```
 0.0  0.4  0.4  0.0 
 0.1  0.0  0.0  0.7 
 0.0  0.2  0.0  0.3 
 0.3  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The matrix `matrix` is converted into a `normal_array` by

```
`val normal_array = matrix.toArray`
```

and I have an array of string

```
inputCols : Array[String] = Array(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

I need to convert this matrix into a following data frame. *(Note: The number of rows and columns in the matrix will be the same as the length of the `inputCols`)*

```
index  p1   p2   p3   p4
 p1    0.0  0.4  0.4  0.0 
 p2    0.1  0.0  0.0  0.7 
 p3    0.0  0.2  0.0  0.3 
 p4    0.3  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

In python, this can be easily achieved by `pandas` library.

```
arrayToDataframe = pandas.DataFrame(normal_array,columns = inputCols, index = inputCols)
```

But how can I do this in `Scala`?

Comment: Can you provide sample output for your requirement as you explained in below comment?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question with example.

Comment: It is very simple to do in Python. I provided my solution using Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
 //convert your data to Scala Seq/List/Array

 val list = Seq((0.0,0.4,0.4,0.0),(0.1,0.0,0.0,0.7),(0.0,0.2,0.0,0.3),(0.3,0.0,0.0,0.0))

  //Define your Array of desired columns

  val inputCols : Array[String] = Array("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4")

  //Create DataFrame from given data, It will create dataframe with its own column names like _c1,_c2 etc

  val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(list)

  //Getting the list of column names from dataframe

  val dfColumns=df.columns

  //Creating query to rename columns

  val query=inputCols.zipWithIndex.map(index=>dfColumns(index._2)+" as "+inputCols(index._2))

  //Firing above query  

  val newDf=df.selectExpr(query:_*)

 //Creating udf which get index(0,1,2,3) as input and returns corresponding column name from your given array of columns

  val getIndexUDF=udf((row_no:Int)=>inputCols(row_no))

  //Adding temporary column row_no which contains index of row and removing after adding index column

  val dfWithRow=newDf.withColumn("row_no",monotonicallyIncreasingId).withColumn("index",getIndexUDF(col("row_no"))).drop("row_no")

  dfWithRow.show
```

Sample Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+
| p1| p2| p3| p4|index|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|0.0|0.4|0.4|0.0|   p1|
|0.1|0.0|0.0|0.7|   p2|
|0.0|0.2|0.0|0.3|   p3|
|0.3|0.0|0.0|0.0|   p4|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: `monotonicallyIncreasingId` - The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not **consecutive**.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way:

```
val data = Seq((0.0,0.4,0.4,0.0),(0.1,0.0,0.0,0.7),(0.0,0.2,0.0,0.3),(0.3,0.0,0.0,0.0))
val cols = Array("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4","index")
```

Zip the collection and convert it into DataFrame.

```
data.zip(cols).map { 
  case (col,index) => (col._1,col._2,col._3,col._4,index)
}.toDF(cols: _*)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|p1 |p2 |p3 |p4 |index|
+---+---+---+---+-----+
|0.0|0.4|0.4|0.0|p1   |
|0.1|0.0|0.0|0.7|p2   |
|0.0|0.2|0.0|0.3|p3   |
|0.3|0.0|0.0|0.0|p4   |
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: I liked this. .

Answer (score 1):

Newer and shorter version should look like
for Spark version > 2.4.5.
Please find the inline description of the statements

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
 import spark.implicits._
 val cols = (1 to 4).map( i => s"p$i")

    val listDf = Seq((0.0,0.4,0.4,0.0),(0.1,0.0,0.0,0.7),(0.0,0.2,0.0,0.3),(0.3,0.0,0.0,0.0))
      .toDF(cols: _*)   // Map the data to new column names
      .withColumn("index",   // Create a column with auto increasing id
        functions.concat(functions.lit("p"),functions.monotonically_increasing_id())) 

    listDf.show()
```